# I cant access to the android xml file in eclipse

Tags: android

I built a android XML file but I cant access it in my code section

[image]
please help me
thank you

Comment: Remove the `import android.R` from the activity imports. see in your picture the first line.

Comment: You are having issues with **Resources**, please make it correct.
Then clean and build application, it will work for you.

Comment: @Clairvoyant ,
 
i'm add `import your.package.R;` and Remove the `import android.R` but problem not solved

Comment: @HirenPatel ,how can i make it correct??!!

Answer (score 0):

remove `import android.R;` and import your R class like this:

`import your.package.R;`

*Added later:*

try: Project - Clean Project

Comment: i'm add `import your.package.R;` but problem not solved

Comment: Do you replace on your own package? What is name of your package?

Comment: yes i create new project and my package name is `ir.saeed.book` and add `import ir.saeed.book.R;` in project.... but when i use `R.layout.item` i have item.xml in layout.... i use _Project -> Clean_ but not solved

Comment: what error you see? please more information about issue

Comment: put red line under `item` and show this error-> _item cannot be resolved or is not a field_